# "latexmk: The Windows command script is not registered."

Tags: pdftex, texworks, latexmk, arara

I usually use `arara` on Mac to compile a document with the `% arara: pdflatexmk` rule. Normally, this works fine. I am now working on Windows (Miktex 2.9), and now arara gives me an error, saying:

```
latexmk: The Windows command script is not registered. 
latexmk: Data: script="latexmk" 
FAILURE.
```

I have no idea what to do. I am not used to Windows. I did not find an answer in the arara manual. Perl seems to be installed (I checked with `perl --version`). `miktex\bin\` is on the path. Compiling with pdfLaTeX using TeXworks also did not work, so this probably is not related to arara alone. Any advice on what to do?

Comment: Which TeX distribution is installed on the Windows machine? Is that distribution in the `PATH` variable? Please give some more details.

Comment: Does `latexmk` work out of the box when invoked in the command prompt or via the TeXworks menu?

Comment: @PauloCereda No it doesn't...it gives me the same error as described in the question.

Comment: Is there actually a Perl shipped with miktex? What exactly does perl-tk version say?

Comment: @daleif out of my league here...what is perl-tk?  After `perl-tk -version`, the prompt says that perl-tk is not recognized as a command.

Comment: Perl-tk is not a programme. It is a bundle of modules for Perl to make graphical programmes. For example the texlive manager is written in Perl and has a gui written using the perl-tk modules (the manager can do even more just on the command line) . Latexmk does not use any of the perl-tk modules. Sorry about the perl-tk in my comment, it was an auto correct on my tablet. I just asked for the Perl version

Comment: I believe that, for some reason, the script could not be executed. Maybe Windows somehow forgot what to do with Perl files. That's really new to me...

Comment: Sorry if it's a dumb idea, but what if you ask the MiKTeX package manager to reinstall `latexmk`? Not that this is the tool's fault, but Windows might be crazy for some odd reason.

Comment: @PauloCereda Not a dumb idea, but did that already. Didn't work.

Comment: @daleif Not at the computer in question anymore, but I will check later. For now, 'solved' the problem by working from home & switching laptops :-(

Comment: There is a reason why I always recommend texlive, even on Windows it just works, and on Windows almost all included scripts work out of the box (there might be some Ruby scripts that need Ruby and of course arara needs java) but latexmk works, nothing needs to be added.

Comment: latexmk works fine for me with miktex. The error message sound as if latexmk is not in scripts.ini -- that is a file that miktex uses to connect wrappers like latexmk.exe to scripts. I have e.g. `latexmk=scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl` in my scripts.ini. Missings scripts means normally either that the scripts.ini is not up-to-date or has been corrupted.